# Expressful Server listening on port 3000. Cannot GET / 404 error

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to run a simple expressful app using the steps on https://github.com/jeroenransijn/expressful/blob/master/docs/total-beginner-guide.md

When I do "node app.js" in the right path I get my console.log Express server started on port 3000 (Expressful server listening on port 3000). 
Although the expressful server is started on port 3000, it gives me an error  "**GET / 404**" when I try to run localhost:3000 on browser.
[refer to this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t12zc.jpg)

And on the browser it displays CANNOT GET /
Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?

P.S. I am working on Windows. npm: v3.10.5, node: v5.4.1

Comment: can you check https://github.com/jeroenransijn/expressful/blob/master/docs/content-routes.md and make sure that you set the routing correctly

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I think going by this link -
 https://github.com/jeroenransijn/expressful/blob/master/docs/total-beginner-guide.md there is no need to set the routing. Just need to run node app.js and open http://localhost:3000/ on browser.

Answer (score -1):

you don't send the route, just add a 'views' folder, and create a `index.html` files in the 'views' folder.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have followed these steps. I didn't send a route. 
Created contents directory, added page.json. Created a views folder, added page.html.
Tried to access localhost:300 on browser and I got the error GET / 404

Comment: @Chirayu you should try to add `index.html` not `page.html` if you try to visit: `localhost:3000` or `http://localhost:3000/index.html`

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well. Still getting the same error!

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are creating a page route, not an index route. You should add a index.json or index.cson and index.html to the content and views directory respectively. I buils this framework btw, let me know if you need any more help.